# Saving to a custom output format in Spark / Hadoop

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark, rdd

I have one RDD which contains multiple datastructures, whereas one of these data structures is a `Map[String, Int]`.

To visualize it easily I get the following after a map transformation:

```
val data = ... // This is a RDD[Map[String, Int]]
```

In one of the elements of this RDD, the Map contains the following:

```
*key value*
map_id -> 7753
Oscar -> 39
Jaden -> 13
Thomas -> 1
Chris -> 52
```

And then it contains other names and numbers in other elements of the RDD, each map contains a certain `map_id`. Anyhow, if I simply do `data.saveAsTextFile(path)`, I will get the following output in my file:

```
Map(map_id -> 7753, Oscar -> 39, Jaden -> 13, Thomas -> 1, Chris -> 52)
Map(...)
Map(...)
```

However, I would like to format it as the following:

```
---------------------------
map_id: 7753
---------------------------
Oscar: 39
Jaden: 13
Thomas: 1
Chris: 52

---------------------------
map_id: <some other id>
---------------------------
Name: nbr
Name2: nbr2
```

Basically, the `map_id` as some kind of header, then the contents, one line of space and then the next element.

To my question, `data` RDD only has two options, save as text file or as object file, which neither as far as I can see support my to customize the formatting. How could I go about doing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just `map` to `String` and write the result. For example:

```
def format(map: Map[String, Int]): String = {
  val id = map.get("map_id").map(_.toString).getOrElse("unknown")
  val content = map.collect {
    case (k, v) if k != "map_id" => s"$k: $v" 
  }.mkString("\n")
  s"""|---------------------------
      |map_id: $id
      |-------------------------------
      |$content
  """.stripMargin
}

data.map(format(_)).saveAsTextFile(path)
```

Comment: Woah, this is really smart, that makes it so simple and easy! Thanks a lot :)